Which program is managing the network for new-installed debian12?
When i install debian12 ,access internet with plugged cable.
uname -a
Linux MiWiFi-R4A-srv 6.1.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Which program  is managing my network now?
sudo systemctl status NetworkManager
○ NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; disabled; pres>
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd
○ systemd-networkd.service - Network Configuration
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; disabled; pr>
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ○ systemd-networkd.socket
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.network1(5)

It is not NetworkManager or systemd-networkd.Which program  is managing network for the new-installed debian?

If you didn’t install a desktop environment during initial system setup, the network is managed by ifupdown. You can configure it by editing /etc/network/interfaces; see man 5 interfaces for details.
ifupdown doesn’t rely on a daemon so you won’t see a running service.
